# Cartoon series: kids disappearing under bed into rectangular blue portals

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It was a kids cartoon. There were rectangular portals that opened on the floor and kids were abducted or could transport through them. In one scene I remember someone running into the room, seeing the portal and lifting the bed up just as the portal closed.

In another kid 1 says "I'll see you in class tomorrow", not knowing the other one is still trapped in the portal.

I can't remember the type of world the portals led to, other than thinking it was a typical 'volcanoish' hell.

I watched this in the 80s-ish. Perhaps 84ish around there; I can't imagine this was in the 90s.

Comment: The time coordinates are already quite precise; if you could have a look at the checklist about [_How to ask a good (anime/manga) Story-ID question?_](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/40711) you might remember additional details (how many kids/boys/girls? how old? are there bizarre sidekicks / items that may be specific of this cartoon?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like the "Dungeons and Dragons" animated series from the 1980s, specifically the episode "The City at the Edge of Midnight" (1984).

The episode started with a young boy (Jimmy Whittaker) in bed, when a portal opened underneath. He got pulled in, shouting for help: his dad broke the door down, but wasn't able to pull him clear. He then flipped the bed up against the wall, but the portal had disappeared so the floor just looked normal (no sign of Jimmy).

It turned out that all the missing children were being forced to work in a giant clock tower, pulling against the mechanisms to stop it from striking midnight. Eventually the main 6 characters broke the spell and sent them all home. They recognised Jimmy, and pleaded with him to pass a message to their parents before he vanished, but he thought that it was all a dream and said "I'll see you at school tomorrow". However, they were stuck in the realm until they could find their own way home.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is the EXACT scene I remember seeing!!!! This is AWESOME. YAYAYAYAYA... can I say thank you? And now that you mention it I sort-of remember the clock tower.

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help :)