Animated TV show I saw in the early '80s in which a group of children go to a secret world
My memory of this show is really vague, I was so young. It was animated. There was a group of children who go to a secret world. I think they get there by going under their bed, or falling through a crack. While there, there is an image of them standing in front of a bridge talking with a skull. That's all I recall. Some kind of dark fantasy made in the '70s or '80s?

Possibly https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226019/cartoon-series-kids-disappearing-under-bed-into-rectangular-blue-portals

It sounds a bit like Potsworth & Co (also known as Midnight Patrol: Adventures in the Dream Zone in America, but I think the UK title fits the humorous vibe better.) The bit about talking to a skull doesn't sound like something it would have had in it, though.
